# Why are my code-snippets adding extra lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

I'm trying to make some code-snippets for C# in Visual studio to make my life easier. However the snippets add an extra line before and after the snippet itself when it's added to the code.

I'm aware i can add $end$ to the snippet to remove the line at the end (which i'll add later) however i still have an extra line above the snippet. I haven't been able to find a solution for this. Unsure if there is one.

Tried the snippet in visual studio 2017 and 2019 with the same result.

Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>NF CustumINotify property</Title>
        <Shortcut>nfprop</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>privatePropertyName</ID>
                <ToolTip>Replace with propertyName</ToolTip>
                <Default>propertyName</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>publicPropertyName</ID>
                <ToolTip>Replace with PropertyName</ToolTip>
                <Default>PropertyName</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Object>
                <ID>type</ID>
                <Type>System.Int64</Type>
                <ToolTip>Replace with property type</ToolTip>
                <Default>int</Default>
            </Object>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="CSharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ _$privatePropertyName$;

  public $type$ $publicPropertyName$
  {
  get => _$privatePropertyName$;
  set => SetField(ref _$privatePropertyName$, value, nameof($publicPropertyName$));
  }]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Code example:

```
public void somefunc()
{

    private $type$ _$privatePropertyName$;

    public $type$ $publicPropertyName$
    {
    get => _$privatePropertyName$;
    set => SetField(ref _$privatePropertyName$, value, nameof($publicPropertyName$));
    }

}
```

Desired output:

```
public void somefunc()
{
    private $type$ _$privatePropertyName$;

    public $type$ $publicPropertyName$
    {
        get => _$privatePropertyName$;
        set => SetField(ref _$privatePropertyName$, value, nameof($publicPropertyName$));
    }
}
```